# LibGDX - Getting the position of a Image inside a table

Tags: image, libgdx, position, actor

I have a little problem inside my libgdx-game:

[image: Screenshot of my game-problem.]

As you can see on the left (marked with a 1.), is the a table inside my stage, and inside this table are 7 images (marked with a 2.).

I added those via:

```
tableInventory.add(new Image(player.getInv().getSlots2()[i].getTexture())).size(16, 16).pad(9.5f).colspan(3).row();
```

my problem is now, I want to get the position of those images inside the table, so can use that (and the size), to use the touchDown()-Method inside my player-class to see, if the mouse clicks on those images.

I tried to get the Cells of the Table, to get to the Images, but it says those cells are null.

So, how do I get the Images' Position? Or is there a easier way to check, if the image(Actor?) has been clicked?

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way. Just attach a `ClickListener` to the images. The `Stage` will make sure to transform the input coordinates correctly and find the correct `Actor` that has been clicked.

```
Image image = new Image(player.getInv().getSlots2()[i].getTexture());
image.addListener(new ClickListener() {@Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("Image was clicked.");
    }});
tableInventory.add(image).size(16, 16).pad(9.5f).colspan(3).row();
```

Comment: Does this work the same, if the Images aren't Images?
(Those Images - as I called them - are Items (a class that I created, which extends a Sprite)

Comment: Oh, no in this case it doesn't work. You could extend `Actor` and have a Sprite field which you render. `Stage` only works with `Actor`s and those are the ones you can attach those `EventListener`s to.